# How to perform derivative on unchanged variable

Tags: limits, partial-derivative

According to [Skeletonization: A Technique for Trimming the Fat from a Network via Relevance Assessment](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1988/file/07e1cd7dca89a1678042477183b7ac3f-Paper.pdf)

It first define a scale parameter $a_i\in[0,1]$, if $a_i=0$, weight $w_i$ contribute $0$ to rest of the network, whereas $a_i=1$, $w_i$ works as usual. Then the relavance of unit $i$ is defined as changes of final error:
$$\rho_i=E_{a_i=0}-E_{a_i=1}$$

The approximiation of $\rho$, $\hat\rho$:
$$lim_{r\rightarrow1}\frac{E_{a_i=r}-E_{a_i=1}}{r-1}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_i}\Bigg|_{a_i=1}$$

Assumming equality holds approximiately for $r=0$:

$$\frac{E_{a_i=0}-E_{a_i=1}}{-1}\approx\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_i}\Bigg|_{a_i=1}$$

we have $-\hat\rho_i\approx\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_i}\Bigg|_{a_i=1}$

However, the approximation assume $a_i=1$, $a_i$ never need be changed.
Then shouldn't $a_i$ is a constant? How can we derive partial derivative respect to $a_i$?

Comment: This seems to be just approximating the derivative with the secant slope. If $r=0$ that’s not assuming $a_i=1.$

Comment: $\left.\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right\rvert_{x=1}$ is the partial derivative with respect to $x$, evaluated at the points where $x=1$.  It does not assume $x$ is *always* $1$. So: $$\begin{align}\left.\dfrac{\partial (x^2+2xy+y^2)}{\partial x}\right\rvert_{x=1} &= \big[2x+2y\big]_{x=1}\\&=2+2y\end{align}$$

Comment: @KevinArlin My understanding is that it assume the approximation could extent to $r=0$, they share the same tangent line? then the equation holds